# Unit test Coverage percentage %0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing

I have written a simple application with a class that returns a boolean value. Here is my class:

```
class Functions {


    func someMethod() -> Bool{

        return true

    }

}
```

And i have written a simple Unit test class to test Functions class. Such as:

```
import XCTest
@testable import simpleApplication

class FunctionsTests: XCTestCase {

    func testSomeMethod(){

        let operation = Functions()


        XCTAssertTrue(operation.someMethod())

    }

}
```

The unit test passes. However the coverage is %0. You can see the coverage image [image: here]. Any idea?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in your `someMethod()` to ensure that it's called by the test?

Comment: Yes it is getting called i have tested it.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you need to delete your project's derived data and try running the tests again.

Comment: Deleting derived data and cleaning project not solved the problem.

Comment: @ridvankucuk Were you able to solve this

Comment: @NaveenRamanathan what have you done so far? Removing the test target from the class in the bundle solved my problem in fact.

Comment: @ridvankucukYou made my day. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the test target from my class (Functions in my case) resolved my problem. If you don't include the tests in the target membership of your class, everything should work.